# How can we get a contradiction?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How could we show that the problem $$u_{tt}(x, t)-u_{xt}(x, t)=0, x \in \mathbb{R}, t \in \mathbb{R}, \\ u(x, -x)=0, x \in \mathbb{R}, \\ u_t(x, -x)=x, x \in \mathbb{R}$$ doesn't have any smooth solution??

Do we have to suppose that there is a smooth solution?? But how can we get a contradiction??

Comment: is evinda = mary star?

Comment: No, why do you think so?? @abel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u_{tt}(x,t)-u_{xt}(x,t)=0$

$u_t(x,t)-u_x(x,t)=f_1(x)$

$u_x(x,t)-u_t(x,t)=-f_1(x)$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=1$ , letting $x(0)=0$ , we have $x=s$

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=-1$ , letting $t(0)=t_0$ , we have $t=-s+t_0=-x+t_0$

$\dfrac{du}{ds}=-f_1(x)=-f_1(s)$ , we have $u(x,t)=-\int^sf_1(s)~ds+g(t_0)=f(x)+g(x+t)$

$u_t(x,t)=g_t(x+t)$

$u_t(x,-x)=x$ :

$g_t(0)=x$ , which is impossible.

$\therefore$ There is no solution.

Comment: Why is $g_t(0)=x$ impossible??

Comment: $g_t(0)$ is a constant.

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: Hello @doraemonpaul !!! I want to solve the following problem:

$$u_x(x,y)+(x+y)u_y(x,y)=0 , x+y>1 \\ u(x,1-x)=f(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$$$
and I want to apply the method of characteristics.$$ $$
What initial value do we take in this case?

Comment: @evinda Please ask a new question for your question.

Comment: @doraemonpaul I did... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190644/what-initial-value-do-i-have-to-take-at-the-beginning