# What initial value do I have to take at the beginning?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my lecture notes there is the following example on which we have applied the method of characteristics:

$$u_t+2xu_x=x+u, x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0 \\ u(x,0)=1+x^2, x \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$$$

$$(x(0), t(0))=(x_0,0)$$

We will find a curve $(x(s), t(s)), s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sigma '(s)=\frac{d}{ds}(u(x(s), t(s))=u_x(x(s), t(s))x'(s)+u_t(x(s), t(s))t'(s)$

$$x'(s)=2x(s), x(0)=x_0 \\ t'(s)=1, t(0)=0 \\ \sigma '(s)=2xu_x+u_t=x(s)+u(s), \sigma(0)=u(x(0), t(0))=1+x_0^2$$

$$\dots \dots \dots \dots \dots$$

$$t(s)=s \\ x(s)=x_0e^{2s} \\ \sigma(s)=x_0 e^{2s}+(1+x_0^2-x_0)e^s$$

If $\overline{s}$ is the value of $s$ such that $(x(\overline{s}), t(\overline{s}))=(x_1, t_1)$ then we have $$x_0e^{2\overline{s}}=x_1 \ , \  \overline{s}=t_1 \\ \Rightarrow x_0=x_1e^{-2t_1}, \overline{s}=t_1$$

So for $s=\overline{s}$ we have $$\sigma(\overline{s})=u(x_1, t_1)=x_1 e^{t_1}+x_1^2e^{-3t_1}-x_1e^{t_1}$$

$$$$

I want to apply this method at the following problem:

$$u_x(x, y)+(x+y)u_y(x, y)=0, x+y>1 \\ u(x, 1-x)=f(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$$

What initial value do I have to take at the beginning?

$(x(0), y(0))=(x_0, 1-x_0)$ ?

Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The characteristic curves must start at the boundary of the domain where the initial conditions are given. In your case that's the line $x + y = 1$, for which $x_0 \mapsto (x_0, 1 - x_0)$ is a valid parametrization.

Comment: So can we say $(x(0),y(0))=(x_0,1-x_0)$?

Comment: Yes, your initial conditions are correct. The domain of the pde is the half-plane above the line $x+y=1$. The answer by @doraemonpaul seems to assume that the domain is the half-plane on the right of the line $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

you have found the characteristic curve $(ae^{2t}, t)$ parametrised by $t.$ you can verify that $$\frac{d}{dt} u(ae^{2t}, t) = u_t + 2ae^{2t}u_x = x + u = ae^{2t} + u  $$ the solution is $$u(ae^{2t}, t) = Ce^{-t} + ae^{2t} $$ using the initial condition $u(a,0) = 1 + a^2,$  gives you $C = 1 -a +a^2.$  therefore $$u(ae^{2t}, t) = (1-a+a^2)e^{-t} + ae^{2t}, x = ae^{2t}\to u(x,t)=\left(1 - xe^{-2t}+x^2e^{-4t}\right)e^{-t}+x $$

Answer (score 0):

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=1$ , letting $x(0)=0$ , we have $x=t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=x+y=t+y$ , we have $y=y_0e^t-t-1=y_0e^x-x-1$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}=0$ , letting $u(0)=F(y_0)$ , we have $u(x,y)=F(y_0)=F((x+y+1)e^{-x})$

$u(x,1-x)=f(x)$ :

$F(2e^{-x})=f(x)$

$F(x)=f(\ln2-\ln x)$

$\therefore u(x,y)=f(\ln2-\ln((x+y+1)e^{-x}))=f(x-\ln(x+y+1)+\ln2)$

Comment: So couldn't we pick $(x(0),y(0))=(x_0,1-x_0)$ ?

Comment: @doraemonpaul Your curves start at $(0, y_0-1)$, that's not on the boundary given.

Comment: @Three.OneFour In fact it is no difference, see http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fpde/fpde1101.pdf for the reason.

Comment: Although I couldn't find a reason in your link, you're right of course — I missed the change of behavior of your curves at $y_0 = 0$. Even though everything went well here, I still think that parametrizing the initial value boundary of the domain for the construction of characteristic curves is the "safer" approach.